# Showing data in text boxes before deleting it from access databse

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, textbox

I have one project (C# application) that includes using access database. What i want to do is to show data in text boxes and combo boxes (by id) before deleting it, but it always shows wrong data than i'm looking for (id is four higher than what I'm looking for - if i want 4, it shows me data for 8 etc.)

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\BookCollection.accdb");
    DataTable books = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand command;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowData(int index)
    {
        tbID.Text = books.Rows[index][0].ToString();
        comboBoxTitle.Text = books.Rows[index][1].ToString();
        tbPageNumber.Text = books.Rows[index][2].ToString();
        comboBoxBookType.Text = books.Rows[index][3].ToString();
        tbComment.Text = books.Rows[index][4].ToString();
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sComDelete = "DELETE FROM BOOKS WHERE BookID = @BookID";
        OleDbCommand comDelete = new OleDbCommand(sComDelete, connection);
        comDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", tbID.Text);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            ShowData(Convert.ToInt32(tbID.Text));
            comDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record is deleted.");
            tbID.Text = tbBrStrana.Text = tbKom.Text = comboBoxTitle.Text = comboBoxBookType.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! " + ex1.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing the Index and the BookID

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn There are 5 columns in that table.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the ID of the book, not the index (the row number) inside the datatable.

You can use the Select method of the DataTable to search for the row whose ID is the one passed in the input and then use that row to fill your textboxes

```
public void ShowData(int bookId)
{
    // Select returns an array of DataRows that match the condition
    // in your case probably you have zero or one row returned
    DataRow[] rows = books.Select("BookID = " + bookID);
    if(rows.Length > 0)
    {
        tbID.Text = rows[0][0].ToString();
        comboBoxTitle.Text = rows[0][1].ToString();
        tbPageNumber.Text = rows[0][2].ToString();
        comboBoxBookType.Text = rows[0][3].ToString();
        tbComment.Text = rows[0][4].ToString();

        // Consider also that if you delete the found row 
        // probably you want to keep in synch the in memory datatable
        rows[0].Delete();
        books.AcceptChanges();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working.